# Variable focus word YOAST

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I had a task to add alt and title to the images of goods. I took advantage of the solution that I found in the Internet:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087772/how-can-i-change-meta-alt-and-title-in-catalog-thumbnail-product-thumbnail

The second task. 
How to get yoast focus word variable? I want to use this to form alt and title.